# Error running jekyll on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jekyll

After installing jekyll on ubuntu 14.04 following this http://michaelchelen.net/81fa/install-jekyll-2-ubuntu-14-04/

it showed some warnings, but it said the installation was successful.

Then when I try to check the version using the command jekyll -v

it shows this

> WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
>         listen (< 3.1, ~> 3.0)
>
> WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
>   Please report a bug if this causes problems.
>   /home/ant-ed/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:35:in `block in setup': You have already activated colorator 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires colorator 0.1. Prepending`bundle exec`to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
>       from /home/ant-ed/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in`map'
>       from /home/ant-ed/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
>       from /home/ant-ed/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:95:in`setup'
>       from /home/ant-ed/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:36:in `require_from_bundler'
>       from /home/ant-ed/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.0/exe/jekyll:9:in`'
>       from /home/ant-ed/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/jekyll:22:in `load'
>       from /home/ant-ed/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/jekyll:22:in`'

Should I uninstall jekyll and try to install it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to the directory where the site is located and run:

```
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll -v
```

This `bundle exec` prefix will load the proper gemset as specified in `Gemfile`.

Comment: Then you probably have problems with your ruby conflicts with system one. Follow the recommendation fro http://rvm.io, install `rvm` and redo `bundle install` in jekyll folder. That should help.